# Sqlrelay framework on PHP environment, inconsistency between web and cli

Tags: php, mysql

all.

I'm configured sqlrelay to manage mysql server's pool as the query traffic goes high.
(http://sqlrelay.sourceforge.net/)

I was happy when I successfully installed sqlrelay on my machine, but it does not properly working so far..

For your information, I've installed apache and php, mysql using YUM on centos 6.3.

The thing is, when I see phpinfo() on console (php -i), it prints sql_relay's information in middle of the output. (and query statement using sqlrelay is working well!)

When I see phpinfo() on webpage, however, there is no sql_relay section through the page.. and of cource, query statement using sqlrelay does not working at all.

anyone can help me out to address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Some time has passed, but here's a suggestion for anyone interested. In the first section of phpinfo() output I'd first check that the php.ini where the module is loaded are included. Depending on the configuration you may have a different php.ini for every virtual host.